# JMETER freezes while opening .jmx having POST request calls which has greater than 5Mb data in request body

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is using large template from UI like tables and large heavy UI controls, fills data in it and then save that template.
So the POST request body is greater than 5 MB. That how my jmx is taking 3 hours to load in JMETER plus I am not able to corelate those request. whenever I click on those requests, JMeter freezes.
I have tried increasing JMETER heap upto maximum limit 55GB.

I have tried increasing JMETER heap upto maximum limit 55GB.
please suggest me on how to stop JMETR freeze issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing such big requests into separate external files

Once done you will be able use i.e. [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) functions to read it dynamically on the fly.

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.

You can also take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and [raise an issue](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) for that.